# Image angular 4+

Tags: angular, spring-boot

there is any way to convert file , String or ArrayBuffer of image on byte[] using angular 4 + ? the best way to send complex object with File, String.. attribute to the backend in single post request ?

Answer (score 0):

No specific angular way but javascript/typescript can handle this:

```
function convertBlobToBase64 (input: Blob, callback) {
    const reader$ = new FileReader();
    reader$.onloadend = function () {
        callback(reader$.result);
    };

    reader$.readAsDataURL(input);
}
```

You can use this method like this:

```
  selectedFile: File;

   convertBlobToBase64(file.slice(), result => {
        // result is a base64
        this.selectedFileContent = result;
      });
```

File is what you get from a `<input type="file">` convert the content to a base 64 string and send it via POST. There are more ways to solve this problem but this is a common way of doing it.